# How to Reduce the base64 String Length

Tags: ios, swift, base64

I am trying to convert the Image selected from the `UIImagePickerController` into `base64` String. But the length of the String is about more than `12 Corer`it's making iPhone hang.

This is the code that I using.

```
 func compressImage(img:UIImage) -> String {
    Utill.showProgress()
    var imageData =  Data(UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)! )
    print("***** Uncompressed Size \(imageData.description) **** ")
    imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.025)!
    print("***** Compressed Size \(imageData.description) **** ")
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    let imagesData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)! as NSData
    let strBase64 = imagesData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
    Utill.dismissProgress()
    return strBase64

}
```

Is there any other way to reduce the String, to be around 10K - 30K?

Comment: No I don't think there's a way to reduce the size of the string. If it is really getting hanged due to this, compress your image more and comment/remove the print statements

Comment: even Without compress the image the Hanging issue is still

Comment: Why are you converting data twice in the same method?

Comment: can you print your image size `print(img.size)`? You can resize your image before saving it. Don't use PNG. Save it as jpeg and I would use 0.75 compression quality

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
func convertImageToBase64(image: UIImage)-> String  {

    if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.25){
       let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedString()
       return base64String
    }

   return ""
}
```

Comment: You should provide an explanation of what your code does compared to the original. Code only answer are usually discouraged, since even if they solve the issue, they don't provide a learning experience to any (future) readers and don't allow readers to understand the underlying problem and the solution.